spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory defines restricted resources
I am using Spring Cloud Azure 5.14.0. spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory
I am using OAuth 2.0 authorization code grant flow to enable users in AAD to access my web application. With the default configuration, all URLs require authentication. How can I make some paths publicly accessible without authentication?

You can use WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and override the configure method to allow access to certain paths without authentication. Refer the article.
